# PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class 'Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Page' not found

Tags: php, yii2, dompdf

I am trying to us Dompdf in my yii2 application, but it's showing me an error message.

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class
>   'Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Page' not found

and I don't understand reason of that.

Comment: `use Dompdf\Dompdf;` put this line on the top of your file.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad where are you getting that from? The namespace for `Page` is [`Dompdf\FrameDecorator`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/FrameDecorator/Page.php#L8)

Comment: @Phil please check https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad I did. I even linked directly to the source.

Comment: @phil please see this: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#quick-start

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad unless OP is directly trying to use `Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Page` (which I doubt), they would receive a different error message.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information in this question to even begin debugging the problem. What does your code look like around the location of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run this command to add this extension into your composer.json.

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

OR add this line in your composer.json require section and run `composer update`:

```
"require": {
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.7.0"
},
```

And then in your view access this way.

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```